# Como criar uma api?

Tags: php, api

Vasculhei a internet atrás de tutoriais de exemplo de API em PHP, consulta e inserção em Mysql.

Vocês tem algum exemplo que eu possa usar como teste?

Comment: Da maneira que está, sua pergunta está demasiadamente ampla e foge do escopo definido para o site. Porém, o que você entende por API?

Comment: API não depende da linguagem, mas exemplos de api em PHP tem as pencas na rede, quer um? [veja esse.](https://www.leaseweb.com/labs/2015/10/creating-a-simple-rest-api-in-php/)